# Convert Python Code To Executable For Linux

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

this my code

```
#!/usr/bin/ python
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk(className="My first GUI") # creates root window
# all components of thw window will come here
root.mainloop() # To keep GUI window running
```

it just generates a window.
i want to convert it into an executable file for Linux based machines i.e(when clicked on the executable file it should display the window directly).
i don't want the user to run it from terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Just put this in the first line of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Make the file executable with

```
`chmod +x GuiFile.`py
```

Execute with

```
./GuiFile.py
```

for Windows, you can use `py2exe` or `pyinstaller`

Answer (score 0):

The first line needs to be:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

(no space before 'python'), and the script needs to be marked executable (`chmod +x scriptname`)

Comment: i get what you are saying is to make the script executable and then run it. i can do that but what i need is to convert the file into a format where anyone can click on it and it will execute the code in it.

Comment: If you (double-)click on a script the system will execute the code in the script.  Do you want to someone else to be able to run the script without installing Python?

Comment: python will be already available in another machine. just make the file executable is what i need. i don't want the other user to make it executable or run it from terminal